# java JFrames

Tags: netbeans6.5

is there a way i could make a button display a form only once?
that is i have two jframe(courses and main page);at one jframe (main page),i have a jbutton that when i click on it the other jframe opens(the code at the button's event:

courses frame=new courses();
   frame.setVisible(true);

but the issue is that i want when the jframe opens and i click on the button agin while it is open, not to display the the same form again not unless i have closed the opened one.

Thanks in advance

Comment: You should rephrase the name to a question. For example: "How to display a JFrame only once on button-click?" Also it woul be better to change the tags to match the content of your question as it does not have anything to do with netbeans6.5. Possible Tags: Java Swing JFrame

Answer (score 1):

Don't `new courses()` everytime you click the button.  Put the variable as a field in you main class.

Answer (score 1):

You should add the frame as a member of the class, then when the button is clicked you can do:

```
if (this.frame == null)
    this.frame = new courses();

if (!this.frame.isVisible())
    this.frame.setVisible(true);
```